# запрос к vk api Json

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api, asp

Есть некоторые запрос который надо кинуть с сервера на vk.api

Допустим :

```
https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?.........
```

Необходимо структуру полученную в JSON формате затем распарсить. Интересует как кидать запрос с сервера и брать полученную структуру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вызова запроса из кода программы по протоколу Http в C# существует реализация

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/");
```

про которую подробно можно прочитать [на офф.сайте](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx)

для эмуляции запроса POST необходимого для отправки данных в BODY в формате x-www-form-urlencoded вам поможет вот такой метод

```
//адрес запроса
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
//Ключи POST запроса
var postData = "thing1=hello";
    postData += "&thing2=world";
//формирования тела запроса
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
//Метод запроса
request.Method = "POST";
//Формат передаваемых данных
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

//Контейнер ответа
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
//Получаем ответ 
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
//Выводим ответ в строку
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Описание взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post), пост рекомендован к прочтению, там ответы на все наиболее распространённые вопросы

Comment: Легче WebClient использовать